# How do I create dynamic rows in Vue.js that behave independently?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic, row, html-select

I have a vue instance that creates dynamic rows. The row has two Select Options:
`Person` and `Interests` with an `Add row` button. These Select Options are dependent options:

[image]

If I select `Brian` as the `Person`, his `Interests` in the second Select Options should load Brian's interests. This works well:

[image]

**Problem:**

This works fine, however the strange thing that I cannot overcome is when a second row is added, **the second-row deletes** Brian's Interests and Populates the second persons interests:

[image]

Brian isn't interested in `Crossfit` for instance - these are Candice's options. In essence, Brian's options are not preserved, they are overwritten with Candices - so both rows show Candices interests.

Can anyone advise on what I need to do to correct the problem? I have created a Jsfiddle to illustrate the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/syed263/y9emdLvr/45/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
          Person:
          <select type="text" v-model="input.one" v-on:change="updateList(input.one)">  
             <option v-for= "options in person._person" v-bind:value ="options">
                {{ options.name }}
             </option>
          </select> Interests:
          <select type="text" v-model="input.two"> 
             <option v-for= "options in activity._activity" v-bind:value ="options">
                {{ options.name }}
             </option>
          </select>
          <button @click="deleteRow(index)">Delete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button @click="addRow">Add row</button>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

**JS: declaration**

```
let _people = {

  _person: [{
      name: 'Adam',
      age: '16',
      ID: '2009121',

    },
    {
      name: 'Brian',
      age: '18',
      ID: '2009122',

    },
    {
      name: 'Candice',
      age: '16',
      ID: '2009120',

    },
  ]
}

let _interests = {

  _activity: [{
    name: '',
    type: '',

  }, ]
}

let person
```

**JS Methods:**

```
const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    inputs: [],
    person: _people,
    activity: _interests,
  },

  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.inputs.push({
        one: '',
        two: ''
      })
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1)
    },
    updateList(val) {
      this.activity._activity = [];

      if (val.name == "Adam") {
        this.activity._activity.push({
          name: 'Badminton',
          type: '20'
        }, {
          name: 'Football',
          type: '30'
        })
      } else if (val.name == "Brian") {
        this.activity._activity.push({
          name: 'Basketball',
          type: '90'
        }, {
          name: 'Karate',
          type: '50'
        })
      } else if (val.name == "Candice") {
        this.activity._activity.push({
          name: 'Climbing',
          type: '90'
        }, {
          name: 'Cross Fit',
          type: '100'
        })
      }

    }
  }

})
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/syed263/y9emdLvr/45/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `this.activity._activity`(every row use the same) to generate the `<option>`
But in `updateList()` whenever the first select value change ,  no matter which row, 
it will change `this.activity._activity`.
And it will affect all second select options, every row.
So you should do something to link `activity` to each row.
Sample code like below, it works, but not perfect.

```js
let _people = {

  _person: [{
      name: 'Adam',
      age: '16',
      ID: '2009121',

    },
    {
      name: 'Brian',
      age: '18',
      ID: '2009122',

    },
    {
      name: 'Candice',
      age: '16',
      ID: '2009120',

    },
  ]
}

let _interests = {

  _activity: [{
    name: '',
    type: '',

  }, ]
}

let person


const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    inputs: [],
    person: _people,
    activity: _interests,
  },

  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.inputs.push({
        one: '',
        two: '',
        activity: [] // To link activity with each row
      })
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1)
    },
    updateList(val, index) {
      this.activity._activity = [];

      if (val.name == "Adam") {
        // only change current row's second option
        this.inputs[index].activity =[{
          name: 'Badminton',
          type: '20'
        }, {
          name: 'Football',
          type: '30'
        }]
      } else if (val.name == "Brian") {
        this.inputs[index].activity =[{
          name: 'Basketball',
          type: '90'
        }, {
          name: 'Karate',
          type: '50'
        }]
      } else if (val.name == "Candice") {
        this.inputs[index].activity =[{
          name: 'Climbing',
          type: '90'
        }, {
          name: 'Cross Fit',
          type: '100'
        }]
      }

    }
  }

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="app">

      <ul>
        <li v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
          Person:
          <select type="text" v-model="input.one" v-on:change="updateList(input.one, index)">  
      <option v-for= "options in person._person" v-bind:value ="options">
      {{ options.name }}
      </option>
    
    </select> Interests:
          <select type="text" v-model="input.two"> 
      <option v-for= "options in input.activity" v-bind:value ="options">
      {{ options.name }}
      </option>
        
     </select>
          <button @click="deleteRow(index)">Delete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button @click="addRow">Add row</button>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```